# CGContextShowTextAtPoint and white space

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, core-text

Why is it that the following code ignores the white-space? [image]

```
UIColor *textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153.0/255.0 green:102.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [textColor CGColor]);
CGContextSelectFont(ctx, "Helvetica Neue Bold" , 14, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextMatrix(ctx, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)); 
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0), 1.0, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
//CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(ctx, YES);

NSString *str = @"test1   test2";
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(ctx, 5, 17, [str UTF8String], str.length);
```

Where as changing the font name to "Helvetica Neue" produces the white space: [image]

Does anyone understand whats going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CGContextShowTextAtPoint()` is not the right way to show text using CoreGraphics, as misleading as that function name may be. Try [CoreText](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html) instead.

Comment: Interesting, why show text isn't the right way to show text using CoreGraphics? I ended up changing the font to something else to go around this but would love to revert that change and more importantly understand the reason behind this. Thanks you!

Comment: CoreGraphics’ text API doesn’t support anything but Roman scripts, doesn’t support fallback fonts (using characters from another font when your font is missing them), or any sort of realy text layout aside from plain advances (including features present in many of the fonts that ship on the system). CoreText supports all these and more, with a nice API to boot.

Comment: Thanks! Very good info, where did you find them? :) I have been looking all over to more understand this. Thank you so much.

Comment: In the [Quartz Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_text/dq_text.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH213-TPXREF101): “iOS 3.2 and later and Mac OS X both support Core Text…designed for high performance and ease of use and allows you to draw Unicode text directly to a graphics context…

If your application needs nothing more than Quartz 2D's limited ability to render MacRoman glyphs in a graphics context, then read this chapter.”