# How to convert Text to Image in Cocoa Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm looking for a way to convert a piece of text to an image in Cocoa.  Everything seems to describe converting an image to text not text to an image.

Simply put, I would like to take a word (such as "Kevin") and convert it into a bitmap image to manipulate and save as a JPEG.

The people giving answers are awesome.  Thank you for three different and equally valid ways to do it(yes i've tested them)....Very cool I wish I could give you all correct answers.

Comment: @hypercrypt invalid edit. This is about Cocoa, not cocoa touch. rolled back.

Comment: As someone who has done text in both Cocoa and Windows GDI, I have to say, the Windows GDI method (`ScriptItemize` -> `ScriptShape` -> `ScriptPlace` -> etc.) requires about 3x as much code for the same functionality in Cocoa.  (GDI ain't exactly the latest API, but still.)

Comment: Actually using C# you simply create a bitmap and the bitmap object has a built in ability to write text at x,y coordinates.  It's stupidly simple.

Comment: Here is the code C# Style

Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("C:\\myImage.jpg");

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);

g.DrawString("My\nText", new Font("Tahoma", 40), Brushes.White, new PointF(0, 0));

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III My bad, it was tagged as iOS at the time of my edit...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: I misread the question and assumed you wanted Cocoa-touch code (I've left it at the end in case you did). Here is one way of doing it in Cocoa using CoreText (as another poster says there are a bunch of ways):

```
{
    NSString* string = @"Kevin";
    CGFloat fontSize = 12.0f;

    // Create an attributed string with string and font information
    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Helvetica Light"), fontSize, nil);
    NSDictionary* attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                (id)font, kCTFontAttributeName, 
                                nil];
    NSAttributedString* as = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes];
    CFRelease(font);

    // Figure out how big an image we need 
    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)as);
    CGFloat ascent, descent, leading;
    double fWidth = CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, &ascent, &descent, &leading);

    // On iOS 4.0 and Mac OS X v10.6 you can pass null for data 
    size_t width = (size_t)ceilf(fWidth);
    size_t height = (size_t)ceilf(ascent + descent);
    void* data = malloc(width*height*4);

    // Create the context and fill it with white background
    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, 8, width*4, space, bitmapInfo);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(space);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // white background
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height));

    // Draw the text 
    CGFloat x = 0.0;
    CGFloat y = descent;
    CGContextSetTextPosition(ctx, x, y);
    CTLineDraw(line, ctx);
    CFRelease(line);

    // Save as JPEG
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    NSBitmapImageRep* imageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
    NSAssert(imageRep, @"imageRep must not be nil");
    NSData* imageData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil];
    NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Kevin.jpg"];
    NSString* fileDirectory = NSHomeDirectory();
    NSString* filePath = [fileDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    // Clean up
    [imageRep release];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    free(data);
}
```

This is the cocoa-touch version:

```
// Figure out the dimensions of the string in a given font.
NSString* kevin = @"Kevin";
UIFont* font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
CGSize size = [kevin sizeWithFont:font];
// Create a bitmap context into which the text will be rendered.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
// Render the text 
[kevin drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) withFont:font];
// Retrieve the image
UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
// Convert to JPEG
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
// Figure out a safe path
NSArray *arrayPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                    NSDocumentDirectory,
                                    NSUserDomainMask,
                                    YES);
NSString *docDir = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
// Write the file
NSString *filePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Kevin.jpg"];
BOOL success = [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
if(!success)
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to write to file. Perhaps it already exists?");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"JPEG file successfully written to %@", filePath);
}
// Clean up
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

When I made started iOS programming I found the following things unintuitive or unusual. The methods to measure and draw strings are methods on `NSString` (not the graphics context as in other systems). The method to save the data is a method on `NSData` not a file class! The functions to create the graphics context are plain C functions and not part of any class.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would be great, if this was for iPhone, but the original question was tagged cocoa, not cocoa touch.

Comment: Although all three are great great examples, this one puts it on a copy and paste level for rookies despite my belief there are simpler ways to write this.

Comment: This does not produce an exact bounding box. For example try `y` and you'll see there is way too much space at the top.

Comment: If you want an exact bounding box use `CTLineGetImageBounds ` see: https://developer.apple.com/reference/coretext/1510967-ctlinegetimagebounds?language=objc

Answer (score 5):

There are, (fortunately or unfortunately), a number of different ways to do this.

**Version 1:** AppKit/Foundation only

```
NSString *text = ...;
NSDictionary *attr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24], NSFontAttributeName,
    nil];
NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(250, 250)];
[img lockFocus];
[text drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(10, 10) withAttributes:attr];
[img unlockFocus];

// when you want to write it to a JPEG
NSData *dat = [NSBitmapImageRep
    representationOfImageRepsInArray:[img representations]
    usingType:NSJPEGFileType
    properties:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9], NSImageCompressionFactor,
        nil]];
```

Then you can write `dat` to a file as you see fit.

**Version 2:**

The same can be accomplished using `CGContextRef` (creating a bitmap context), and the equivalent Quartz APIs.  This obviates the need for Objective C, but the code will be a little longer as a result.  You can also use various mixtures of the Quartz (`CGxxx`) and AppKit (`NSxxx`) APIs, but the Quartz APIs are generally more cumbersome to use (because of their flexibility wrt. allocation and other concerns).

**Version 3:**

You can also use Quartz + Core Text, which is OS X 10.5+.  This allows you a lot of flexibility in terms of exactly how your text is laid out, and also provides a relatively easy way to measure how big the text is before you draw it to a bitmap (so you can make the bitmap large enough).

**Footnote:** Things like skew are easy enough to apply before you draw the text.  The text can be drawn with skew (see `NSAffineTransform` and the [Cocoa drawing guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH204-BCIDJJBI)).

Comment: This one should be considered as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the function you want is [`CGContextShowTextAtPoint()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextShowTextAtPoint).

Example usage:

```
NSString *input = /* ... */;
CGContextRef context = /* create a graphics context */;

// make sure you have set up the font
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 5, 5, [input UTF8String], [input length]);
```

Comment: Would this allow me to save it as an image?

Comment: In general you should use a higher-level API, because CGContextShowTextAtPoint() has a number of well known deficiencies. [One example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429004/cgcontextshowtextatpoint-and-white-space), and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910756/ios-convert-nsstring-with-special-chars-to-const-char).

Comment: No need to drop down to the CG level.  NSString and NSAttributedString both have drawing methods.

Comment: I'll be damned NSResponder is right.  You do still need a context to draw it in however.

Comment: The simplest way to get somewhere to draw it is to create an NSImage instance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a minimal command line tool that does what you described.  Pass it the path where you want save the result, e.g:

"`./test foo.tiff`"

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
      NSString *string = @"Hello, World!";
      NSString *path = [[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] objectAtIndex:1];

      NSDictionary *attributes =
        @{ NSFontAttributeName : [NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:40.0],
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : NSColor.blackColor};

      NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[string sizeWithAttributes:attributes]];
      [image lockFocus];
      [string drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint withAttributes:attributes];
      [image unlockFocus];
      [[image TIFFRepresentation] writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know if there is a difference between command line and windowed program as again I'm coming from a M$ world, but this seems to compile fine but throws a context error.